# Angular:- routing of parent component based on child component value

Tags: angular

Need to do routing on parent component level. Can't do routing with query params on child level. I need to do event emitter from child to parent and at parent component set up routing. Because child component is a shared component.

```
/// parent.html

    <child-shared-comp></child-shared-comp>
    .........................
    child-shared-component.ts

    func(dateSelected:date){
    If(condition statisfy){
    then should enable routing to another page
    using query params   { queryParams: date }
    }

    }
```

On click func(), which is in child component, whole page including parent component should change( I meant route to another page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieves this is adding an Output to the child component that emits when function "func()" fires, it's a good way to communicate between child to parent components.

Example:

```
/// parent.html

    <child-shared-comp (dateSelected)="dateSelected($event)"></child-shared-comp>

// parent.component.ts
    ...
    dateSelected(selectedDate: Date) {
      //routing {queryParams: selectedDate}
    }

//child-shared-component.ts

    import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

    @Output() dateSelected: EventEmitter<Date> = new EventEmitter<Date>();

    func(dateSelected: Date){
     If(condition statisfy){
       this.dateSelected.emit(dateSelected);
     }
    }
```

For more information about Output:
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#input-and-output-properties